# Argument for function to edit an array of structs

Tags: c

I have a Array of structs `struct npc sum[arraysize];` in which every struct represents an NPC with different integer values. I want to loop-through `sum[i]` a set number of times and call a function:

`int performTask(argument???);`

This function is supposed to update some integers in the structs (such as one for experience), and return how much experience the npc currently has.

However, I am obviously doing things wrong because whatever I into the function isn't saved in the array. I have tried to pass the struct contained in `sum[1]` into the function for example. Also to pass pointers as an argument but can't get that to work either.

What would be the proper argument to send in this function in order to edit the structs already saved in the array?

Or more generally, how can I update an array of structs with a function?

Comment: post your code even if it not work, it would be easier to help.

Comment: Give an example with your code, and read about how to pass elements by reference in C.

Comment: Take the [tour], read [ask], and [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to pass an array of struct (or an array of anything), simply pass a pointer. An array, on access, is converted to a pointer<sup>1</sup>.

The only caveat is if you are passing the address for a linked list to a function where the list address may change (in that case you must pass the **address of** the pointer so that the list address may be changed if the first node is changed)

Otherwise, in your case, as long as there has been storage allocated for the array of struct prior to passing to the function, simply passing a pointer is fine, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NS 4

typedef struct {    /* structure */
    int a, b;
} ints;

void change (ints *s)   /* function taking pointer to struct */
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NS; i++)
        s[i].a = i+1, s[i].b = i+1;
}

int main (void) {

    ints arr[NS] = {{0}};   /* array of struct initialized zero */

    change (arr);           /* passed to function */

    for (int i = 0; i < NS; i++)    /* changes output */
        printf ("arr[%d]: (%d, %d)\n", i, arr[i].a, arr[i].b);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/structpass
arr[0]: (1, 1)
arr[1]: (2, 2)
arr[2]: (3, 3)
arr[3]: (4, 4)
```

**footnotes:**

**[1]** [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3)

Comment: Thanks alot. Seems like I wasn't far off, didn't know you could iterate with a pointer like that. Very quick and thorough answer!

Comment: Just remember when working with an array of struct when passed as a pointer, the `[..]` serves as a **dereference** of the pointer. So if you pass an array of struct as `struct foo *arr` then `arr[i]` is a dereference of the pointer leaving type `struct foo` requiring the use of the `'.'` (dot) operator to access the *members* instead of the `'->'` (arrow operator) you use when dereferencing a *pointer to struct*. The `[..]` already serves as the dereference here.

Answer (score 0):

```
int performTask(struct npc**sums)
{
// to hit sums 5
    sums[5]->thingy = 42;
}
```

note that you will also have to pass in a size argument. There is no way to determine the size of the array in `performTask`